# Derivation of $V(\bar{y})$ using random component of the sample $\tau$ for SRS

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, sampling

I am trying to derive this formula:
[image]

but I do not understand the parts underlined by red (I do not get from where they were derived)

Here's my attempt (sorry it's handwritten, it would take me so long to write it in mathjax):

[image]

Edit: $Var(\bar{y})$ = $(1-f)\frac{S^2}{n}$ and it's the final form we need to reach (where $n$ is sample size and $(1-f)$ is the finite population factor.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the $\tau_i$ ? Are they independent of $Y_i$ ? What is $f$ ? Why do you have $$\mathbb E\left[\sum Y_i\tau_i\right] = \sum Y_i\mathbb E\left[\tau_i\right]$$
And what exactly is it that you're asking for ? Can you edit and clarify your question please ? (also, even if it takes time, please try using MathJaX as much as possible to typeset equations)

Comment: @StratosFair Yes $\tau$ is independent of $Y_i$, it's basically the random component of $Y_i$, $f$ is the finite population factor.

Comment: @StratosFair I know for sure there are easier ways to derive the variance of sample mean, but my professor chooses to derive it using this old approach (If you think so) - this derivation is part of my **sampling course** btw